# Why remember_token doesn't generated when i tried to login ( Laravel 8 )

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-8

So this is my login code

```
function checklogin(Request $request){
    $this->validate($request,[
        'nip'   => 'required',
        'password'  => 'required'
    ]);
    
    $akun_data = array(
        'nip' =>  $request->get('nip'),
        'password'  =>  $request->get('password')
    );
    if(Auth::attempt($akun_data)){
        return redirect('login/successlogin');
    }else{
        return back()->with('message','NIP or Password is wrong');
    }
   
}
```

and this is my logout code :

```
function logout(){
    $akun = Auth::user();
    $akun_data = Akun::find($akun->nip);
    $akun_data->status = "offline";
    $akun_data->save();
    Auth::logout();
    session()->flush();
    return redirect('login');
}
```

So i tried to login with the 1st account and it generates the remember_token of that account, then logout it. But when i tried to login with another account it didn't generate new remember token and the remember_token column of the account still NULL. I have 3 accounts data in database , but it just works with the first account.

**The first account is automatically generated with a seeder, other accounts generated manually with a form.**

and this is the code to add another account manually with form :

```
Akun::create([
        'nip' => $request->get('nip'),
        'password' => Hash::make($request->get('password')),
        'status' => "offline",
    ]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because you are not setting a value for `remember_token` when creating a new user via your form.

```php
Akun::create([
    'nip' => $request->get('nip'),
    'password' => Hash::make($request->get('password')),
    'status' => "offline",
    'remember_token' => Str::random(10),
]);
```

When logging in you checkbox for remember me should be checked on the login form for remember_token to be filled while handling login at controller level

Comment: but is it normal , when i logout the remember_token changed? because it's automatically changed

Comment: I guess yes. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authentication#remembering-users